# How to use `\thanks` with mutiple beamer presentations

Tags: beamer

I have previously created some `beamer` presentations. Now, due to my thesis presentation, I need to create one complete presentation (one big presentation that successively contains all smaller presentations). So, I am using `\input{<filename>.tex}`. Right now, I am with two presentations only.

Now, the problem is with the `titlepage` of the second presentation - it contains `footnote`s (`\thanks`) from the first presentation. Please refer to the image.

[image]

**MWE**

`c1.tex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\input{c2}
\input{c3}
\end{document}
```

`c2.tex`

```
\author{a\thanks{a}, b\thanks{b}}

\section{start}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
Frame 1/1
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 2/1
\end{frame}
```

`c3.tex`

```
\author{c\thanks{c}, d\thanks{d}}

\section{start-2}
\maketitle

\begin{frame}
Frame 1/2
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Frame 2/2
\end{frame}
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Your final presentation deserves some manual action no? This is very easily fixed by removing the title pages of your subpresentations.

Comment: @percusse *"by removing the title pages"* -actually I don't want to do that...

Answer (score 3):

You just need to empty the internal variable `\@thanks` manually:

```
\begin{document}
\author{a\thanks{a}, b\thanks{b}}

\maketitle

\makeatletter
\def\@thanks{}
\makeatother

\author{c\thanks{c}, d\thanks{d}}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```